# Eigenstates and Standard Deviation of an Operator

Tags: operators, hilbert-space, linear-algebra

I have been asked to prove that, for an Hermitian operator A, its standard deviation $\Delta_{\varphi}$ in a certain state $|\varphi\rangle$ is equal to $0$ if, and only if, said state is an eigenstate. In other words:

$$
\Delta_{\varphi}A\ \equiv\ \langle \varphi|A²|\varphi\rangle-\langle \varphi|A|\varphi\rangle²=0\Leftrightarrow A|\varphi\rangle=a_{\varphi}|\varphi\rangle
$$

I was able to prove the $\Leftarrow$-relation trivially using the definitions, but not the $\Rightarrow$. Can someone shed a light on this?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\Delta_\phi A=0$. Set $|\psi\rangle=A|\varphi\rangle$. Then $|\varphi\rangle$ being an eigenvalue of $A$ is equivalent to $|\psi\rangle$ being proportional to $|\varphi\rangle$. Suppose we have an orthonormal basis $|n\rangle$ where $|0\rangle\equiv|\varphi\rangle$. Then $\langle\psi|\psi\rangle=\langle\varphi|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|\varphi\rangle=|\langle\varphi|\psi\rangle|^2$ and if we expand $\langle\psi|\psi\rangle$ in the basis $\{|n\rangle\}$ we obtain:
\begin{align}
\langle\psi|\psi\rangle&=\sum_n\langle\psi|n\rangle\langle n|\psi\rangle \\
&= |\langle  0|\psi \rangle|^2+(\text{nonnegative}).
\end{align}

But $\langle\psi|\psi\rangle=|\langle\varphi|\psi\rangle|^2=|\langle 0|\psi\rangle|^2$. So $\langle n|\psi\rangle=0$ for $n\neq 0$. This shows that $|\psi\rangle$ is proportional to $|\varphi\rangle$.